# I need help trying to reverse logic in an IF statement in Unity C#

Tags: c#, if-statement, unity-game-engine

I'm using a simple GameObject[] which uses Game Objects as "navPoints" for a navAgent to move to.

I have a method which works simply like this:

```
  public void pickNextNavPoint()
    {
        ++navIndex;
        if (navIndex >= myNavPoints.Length)
            navIndex = 0;

    }
```

I then use a method :

```
public void FindDestination()
    {
        GetComponent<NavMeshAgent> 
        ().SetDestination(myNavPoints[navIndex].transform.position);

    }
```

This makes my NavAgent go to a NavPoint, then the next one and so on.

My question is simply, how can I alter this method to make it go in reverse using the same simple logic?

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
public void PickNextNavPoint() {
    MoveIndex(1);
}

public void PickPreviousNavPoint() {
    MoveIndex(-1)
}

private void MoveIndex(delta) {
    navIndex += delta;
    // Constrain navIndex between 0 and len - 1
    navIndex = Math.Min(Math.Max(0, navIndex), myNavPoints.Length - 1);
}
```

As an aside, you should check out the naming guidelines for C#, your methods should be PascalCased, amongst other things.